# how to compare a string from url to NSutf8stringencoding return 1 or 0 with normal string @"1"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I need to compare a string from an url using `NSutf8stringencoding` in order to return 1 or 0, but it always returns 0 even if the string has value 1.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/signup/login.php?username=%@&password=%@",username.text,password.text];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// print the data in strResult
NSLog(@"%@",strResult);

if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    // I need to get the control for main navigation controller 
    login2ViewController *controller = [[login2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"login2ViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES ];

}else
{
    // invalid information
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Invalid Information" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;  
}
```

But it always show invalid informartion even if the content in `strResult` is `1`.
I printed that value by `NSlog`. The output from `NSLog`:

```
2012-12-11 16:06:08.156 friend finder[277:11603] 
1
```

How can I compare that string with `@"1"`?

Comment: May be in strResult there are spaces, not only "1"?

Comment: In order to test @MikhailViceman 's  theory, log the string using `NSLog(@"'%@'", strResult);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following - there could be additional whitespace characters in the strResult (like carriage returns):

```
if ([strResult rangeOfString:@"1"].length > 0) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other characters in the string.

Use

```
[strResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```